# How to create a dataframe from grouped data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (let's call it "csv") that I want to group and get a value of the first element of the group. Example:

```
A   B   C  D
foo bar happy yellow
foo bar sad   green
foo ape last  laugh
```

I would like this as output:

```
A   B   C
foo bar happy
foo ape last
```

I currently do this:

```
grp1 = csv.groupby(['A','B'])
lst = [(A,B,csv.ix[group[0]]['C']) for (A,B),group in grp1.groups.items()]
df = DataFrame(lst,columns=['A','B','C'])
df.to_csv('grp.csv',cols=['A','B','C'],index=False)
```

But this seems inefficient. Do I really have to create a list first, and then create a `dataframe` from that? Isn't there a way to just create a `dataframe` directly, or do some sort of indexing or something on the original `dataframe` so that i can just work with the first record in each group?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate` to define your aggregate function, which will just keep the first element of a column and drop the others.

```
    In [60]: grp = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])

    In [61]: grp.aggregate({'C': lambda c: c.ix[c.first_valid_index()]})
    Out[61]:
                 C
    A   B  
    foo ape   last
        bar  happy
```